# Beginner PowerShell question: how to combine strings that form a command and run the command in the same script?

Tags: string, powershell, syntax, automation

I've been working in IS for several years as a PC tech. Mostly hardware & OS troubleshooting. I generally only use `PS`/`cmd` for basic tasks - lookup serial #, add/default printers, `gpupdate`, `DISM`/`sfc`, etc. I would like to become more familiar with `PowerShell` and creating scripts to start automating some tasks.

Since it is customary I present to you my very bad and wrong code:

```
$PCNAME = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter PC Name"
Write-Output $PCNAME
$CMD = "Enter-PSSession -ComputerName $PCNAME"
iex $CMD
```

Intended purpose:

1. Prompt for PC name input
2. Add the entered PC name to the `Enter-PSSession` command
3. Run `PSSession` command

Just to test if it continues after prompt and executes PSSession command. I've tried quite a few variations using snippets of code I found here and there but I am a PS noob and everything so far either fails to run or exits PS after taking the user's input.

If anyone can show me what a functional version of this looks like I would be greatly appreciative. Thanks!

Comment: Do you want the user to be prompted for further input (to be run in the remote session), or do you already know what commands you want to execute in the session?

Comment: So in this case the user being asked for input is myself, not remote user. I would like to use the script to gather data such as connected device IDs, certain items from system info, run commands from time to time. But sometimes may need to run that script on multiple remote machines. So if I have one premade that asks input for PC name and writes that input to the command = reusable script

Comment: Have a look at [`New-PSSession`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/new-pssession?view=powershell-7.1) and [`Invoke-Command`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/invoke-command?view=powershell-7.1)